# Select only one by css

Tags: html, css

Hi I want to select the "Link" in class beers only but It always select all the  links from sub-menu. I try

```
  .beers:first-child        does not work
  .beers a:nth-child(1)     does not work
  .beers a:first-of-type  (this apply to all the links of sub-menu)

 <ul>
    <li class="beers"><a>Link</a>  only  here
         <ul class="sub-menu">
             <li ><a></a></li>     not here
             <li><a></a></li>      not here
        </ul> 
    </li> 
    <li ><a></a></li>
    <li ><a></a></li>
 </ul>
```

Please help me

Comment: You wants to select in CSS OR Jquery

Comment: I  want to select it in css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use style for `a`

```
 .beers > a{color:green;}
```

If you want to use for `li` you have override

```
 li.beers{ color:green;}
 li.beers ul li{ color:black;}
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can get first element from child as below:**

```
<style>
.beers >a {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to maintain the elements level. Try the below one.

> .beers>a

Answer (score 0):

```
.beers:first-child
```

to

```
.beers li:first-child
```

With:

```
<ul class="beers">
<li><a>Link</a>  only  here
     <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li ><a></a></li>     not here
         <li><a></a></li>      not here
    </ul> 
</li> 
<li ><a></a></li>
<li ><a></a></li>
```

Comment: class="beers" in li not in ul and I can not change that,
I try beers.first-child already